# How to delete line from file which matches string

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, tcl

I have a file which contains below information-

```sh
SOURCE "defrust"

DESIGN "2_3"

SYSTEM SPICE

NETLIST SOURCE

NETS "NONE"

//NETS "NONE"

//VARIABLE "cell2"

DESIGN "hello one"
```

How can i use unix commands to delete full lines which are starting from `SOURCE` ,`DESIGN` and `//`

output be somewhat like-

```
SYSTEM SPICE

NETLIST SOURCE

NETS "NONE"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What have you try?

Comment: Are you looking to edit the file itself, or to get a stream of the lines without the ones you don't want?

Comment: please update the question with the expected output (for the given sample input)

Comment: do you want to delete all lines between `SOURCE` and `DESIGN` or just the lines that start with `SOURCE` and `DESIGN`?  what if `SOURCE`, `DESIGN` or `//` don't start in column 1 (eg, they have leading white space) ... should these lines be kept or removed?

Comment: `grep -Ev '^(SOURCE|DESIGN|//)' input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print if !m{^(SOURCE|DESIGN|//)}' file_name
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`^` : beginning of the line in regex.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)